# How to recursively get scalar value from 2 lists?

Tags: recursion, f#

The task is to get scalar value from 2 lists recursively. I wrote the code that I think should work, but I am having some type related problem

```
let rec scalar2 (a, b) = function
  | ([], []) -> 0
  | ([x : int], [y : int]) -> x * y
  | (h1::t1, h2::t2) -> 
        let sc : int = scalar2 (t1,t2) 
        sc + (h1 * h2)
```

The error is that `scalar2 (t1,t2)` reqested to be int, but it is `int list * int list -> int`

How this problem could be solved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When defining a function using the `function` keyword, you don't need to name your parameters (`a` and `b` here). Note that your function body doesn't refer to `a` or `b` at all. You want `scalar2` to be a function, and the `function` expression on the right hand side results in a function, so just assign this function to `scalar2` directly.

```ml
let rec scalar2 = function
  | ([], []) -> 0
  | ([x : int], [y : int]) -> x * y
  | (h1::t1, h2::t2) -> 
        let sc : int = scalar2 (t1,t2) 
        sc + (h1 * h2)
```

Your mistake is likely caused by a confusion with the usual way of defining a function, which doesn't use the `function` keyword:

```ml
let rec scalar2 (a,b) =
  match (a,b) with
  | ([], []) -> 0
  | ([x : int], [y : int]) -> x * y
  | (h1::t1, h2::t2) -> 
        let sc : int = scalar2 (t1,t2) 
        sc + (h1 * h2)
```

This way you need a `match` expression which does use the parameters `a` and `b`.

Note that both of these definitions are incomplete, since you haven't said what should happen when only one of the lists is non-empty.

---

To explain the type error in the original code, consider how F# evaluates `let sc : int = scalar2 (t1,t2)`. Your original definition says that `scalar2 (a,b) = function ...`, and the left-hand side of this equality has the same form as the expression `scalar2 (t1,t2)`.

So the `scalar2 (t1,t2)` gets replaced with the `function ...` expression, after substituting `t1` for `a` and `t2` for `b`. This leaves `let sc : int = function ...` which of course doesn't type-check.